# Passing NULL to a wrapped C function in Cython

Tags: python, cython

I have a function wrapped in Cython:

```
cdef extern  from "myheader.h":
   int c_my_func (const_char *a, const_char* b)
```

And a function exposed to Python:

```
def my_func(a, b):
    c_my_func(a, b)
```

The function `c_my_func` accepts NULL for parameters `a` and `b`. When I call it from the interpreter:

```
my_func(None, None)
```

it throws the exception:

```
TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, NoneType found
```

How do I make this function accept the `None` and pass `NULL` to the `c_my_func` ? I don't want to manually check for the `None` and then pass NULL. I also tried using default parameters on the cdef of the `c_my_func` and it doesn't worked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can find the answer in the [Cython FAQ](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/FAQ#user-content-what-is-the-difference-between-pyobject-and-object).

> `None` is not compatible with any C type. To accommodate for this, the
>   default behavior is for functions with cdefed parameters to also
>   accept `None`.
>
> 1. If you want to consider `None` invalid input, then you need to write
>      code that checks for it, and raised an appropriate exception.

The solution is to manually check for `None` and pass NULL, as you write.

Comment: For a language that is supposed to do such things for you this is a real fail. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Simply build a wrapper function for your c function calls.  It will work with any number of arguments.

```
def c_func_call(c_func, *args):
   c_func(*[x if x is not None else NULL for x in args])
```

Usage in your example:

```
def my_func(a, b):
    c_func_call(c_my_func, a, b)
```

Comment: What package or module provides NULL ?  Please show the appropriate import.

Comment: In Cython files .pyx u can use NULL.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `not None` like this

```
def widen_shrubbery(Shrubbery sh not None, extra_width):
    sh.width = sh.width + extra_width
```

as exposed [here](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/extension_types.html#extension-types-and-none).